# Combinatorics - HMMT 2023 - Solution Verifiation.

Tags: combinatorics

An entry in a grid is called a saddle point if it is the largest number in its row and the smallest
number in its column. Suppose that each cell in a 3 × 3 grid is filled with a real number, each chosen independently and uniformly at random from the interval [0, 1]. Compute the probability that this grid has at least one saddle point.

Solution is given in here, https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2023/nov/gen/solutions.pdf

But I am using calculus to derive the answer:

For the column, we need to find the minimum of three numbers i.e. $F_{min} (x) = 1 - (1-x)^3$

For the row, we need to find the maximum of three numbers i.e $F_{max}(x)= x^3$

$P_{min} (x) = \frac{d}{dx} F_{min} (x) = 3(1-x)^2$

$P_{max} (x) = \frac{d}{dx} F_{max} (x) = 3x^2$

$P_{saddle} (x) = 9x^2(1-x)^2$ Invoking independence of max and min.

Thus probability that you will have a saddle point $= \int_{0}^{1} 9x^2(1-x)^2 = \frac{3}{10}$

Could someone confirm if this answer is correct?

Comment: [[1]] At the high-level , it looks right , though you have to "Elaborate" on What the 3 numbers are & What $F$ is & Why column term is not matching row term & Why $P$ is involving Derivative & ETC. [[2]] You are not showing the uniqueness of Saddle Point.